# Pass variable into include

Tags: variable, include

I have a snippet within a template which I want to pass a variable into:

**page.twig**

```
{% set lightswitchTest = entry.aktivesProjekt('1').find() %}

{% include '_snippets/thingy' %}
```

**thingy.twig**

```
<div class="panel{% if lightswitchTest == null %} notActive{% endif %}">
   {# bla bla #}
</div>
```

I tried to add pass in the variable with the [with keyword](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) but I guess my syntax is wrong?

```
{% include '_snippets/thingy' with lightswitchTest %}
```

If i use the varibale now in the snippet there is just the *`Array to string conversion`* error.

What am I missing? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can leave the `with lightswitchTest` part off altogether, and all the variables from the parent template will be available inside the include too.

`with` expects an array, where the keys correspond to the variable names and their values, so if you *did* want to explicitly pass that in (say as a different variable) you could use:

**page.twig**

```
{% include "_snippets/thingy" with { active: lightswitchTest } %}
```

**thingy.twig**

```
<div class="panel{% if not active %} notActive{% endif %}">
    {# bla bla #}
</div>
```

Comment: It's also possible to pass the `only` parameter, if you want to exclude other variables from being exposed to the included template: `{% include "_snippets/thingy" with { active: lightswitchTest } only %}`